# Google Tag Manager error: “No HTTP response detected”

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have added the Google Dynamic Re Marketing Tag to my website by use of my GTM account (test@gmail.com) successfully; it was shown with minor warnings in Google Tag Assistant as well. But, when I later switched to another GTM account (original@gmail.com) with the same settings it shows an error: “No HTTP response detected”. How this can happen when both the GTM accounts have the same data ? Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I do not quite understand the question. A GTM account is identified by the account, not by your email adress. Can you clarify ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am using two GTM accounts (test and Original); when I checked with the test account it is found working; but, when moved to original account it is fond not working. Both the accounts having same tags and configuration. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This means clearly the code is not getting executed, could be syntax error, or extra parameters...etc. In my scenario I was sending transaction as part of Ecommerce, 
(ref : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce )

ga('require', 'ec', 'commerce.js'); ///HTTP RESPONSE NOT DETECTED..error.
 ga('require', 'ec'); ///SOLVED THE ISSUE

so on similar grounds, check the syntax!