# Missing HTTP Response for Google Analytics in TYPO3

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, typo3

I have some issue with google analytics. Ot says there is a missing http response.
I am using the code from a TYPO3 template and it works on the whole site, but not on the page I am working on now. So do you have any thoughts, why I may be so?

Here is the link to the page: 
http://www.operation-karriere.de/index.php?id=241

Here is the code from my page.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    var gaProperty = 'UA-11409155-21';
    var disableStr = 'ga-disable-' + gaProperty;
    if (document.cookie.indexOf(disableStr + '=true') > -1) {
      window[disableStr] = true;
    }
    function gaOptout() {
      document.cookie = disableStr + '=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC; path=/';
      window[disableStr] = true;
    }
</script>
<script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
      ga('create', 'UA-11409155-21', 'auto');
      ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
      ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Kind regards,

Andrej

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics [quotes](https://support.google.com/tagassistant/answer/3059154?hl=en#http_response)

> Missing HTTP Response denotes that, while the Google Analytics code
>   was detected in the page source, the script itself did not execute.
>   Each time the Google Analytics script executes, we expect an HTTP
>   Response carrying the tracking request to Google’s servers. This means
>   that the Google Analytics code is not implemented properly on the page
>   and no data will be collected. Recommended Action: Reinstall the
>   Google Analytics snippet by removing the current iteration, copy a new
>   version from the Analytics interface, and insert that version into the
>   site.

Check if there are any JS errors listed in your browser and try the solution proposed by google.

Comment: The chrome plugin "google tag assistant" tells me that you should move it to the head part. https://support.google.com/tagassistant/answer/3059154?ref_topic=2947092#move_head

Comment: you may refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265032/google-tag-manager-error-no-http-response-detected